# How to access or call a function defined as one of Jquery Plugin option parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I call a function defined as JQuery plugin option parameter in my Base Script?

**Plugin**

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(){
   var config = $.extend({
    read:function(){}

})
config.read.call(this);
     
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
$("#someElement").myPlugin({

     read: function myFunc(){
            //some code
          }
});

function anotherFunc(){
     myFunc();
    //here, why I cant call the function myFunc defined as one of my option parameter for Jquery Plugin
}
```

Comment: The function you are passing to `read:` is scoped to the myPlugin init object - you would normally use an anonymous (unnamed) function here as the name is unusable elsewhere (due to its scope):  `read: function() {...`.   Use a global function:  `function myFunc() {` .. `read: myFunc`.

Comment: Oh I see, but is there no other way, I can call `myfunc` function?

Comment: The alternative is to expose/export your `config`.   This answer might help you to create jquery-plugin-style options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457128/2181514   -> `$("#id").myPlugin("read")`  See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25343333/2181514

Comment: Will it be `myPlugin.config.read.call(this)`?. Is it correct?

Comment: No / depends on how you store your config.  That would be a global config `$.fn.myPlugin.config.read...`  but if you have a different config per call to myPlugin then you need to store it on the element itself.  See the above links.